# What does this sentence from textbook mean "we will identify a 1x1 matrix with its single entry"?

Tags: matrices

The context is about **matrix-vector product**

One paragraph says "we will identify a 1by1 matrix with its single entry"

> A is an 1by1 matrix: [*a*_1_1]
>
> *a*_1_1 or *a*_1 is its first component.

and

> v is an 1by1 vector: [*v*_1]
>
> *v*_1 is its first component.

Does "we will identify a 1x1 matrix with its single entry" mean

> Av = [*a*_1_1 multiplies *v*_1]

which is still a matrix

or

> Av = *a*_1_1 multiplies *v*_1

which becomes a scalar

I guess that sentence means

> Av = [*a*_1_1 multiplies *v*_1]

Comment: Yes, every scalar is a $1\times1$ matrix. By abuse of language I'd say that scalars are a particular case of $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^m$ matrices. So when you multiply a $1\times1$ matrix with a $1\times1$ vector, you're technically multiplying two scalars.

Comment: Okay, from the perspective of structure when we do that kind of multiplication, it seems reasonable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means both of these. For any matrix $\mathbf{A} = [a_{11}] \in M_{1\times1}(\mathbb{R})$ we are defining $\mathbf{A} := a_{11}$, and for any scalar $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we are defining $x := [x]$. Similarly, for any vector $\boldsymbol{v} = [v_1] \in \mathbb{R}^1$ we are defining $\boldsymbol{v} := v_1$.

Thus, $\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{v} = [a_{11}v_1] = a_{11}v_1$.

We are defining scalars as identical to $1 \times 1$ matrices, and $1 \times 1$ matrices as identical to scalars, and as such you may freely interconvert between them.

We may do this as under normal matrix addition and multiplication, and under componentwise addition and the normal vector dot product, $(M_{1\times1}(\mathbb{R}), +, \cdot) \cong (\mathbb{R}^1, +, \cdot) \cong (\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$.